# Gap appearing between one row of text box items in a grid but not others - can't figure out why

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Have moved on to teaching myself WPF, rather than continuing along with winforms. I haven't gotten into the more detailed aspects of binding yet, trying to get my first run interface done beforehand so I have a better grasp of how the xaml and code behind file works together. Anyway, I'm trying to build a table with four rows of inputs, each of 11 columns, with the 11th column being combo boxes. All other inputs are text boxes. the code below produces a table with borders all of thickness 2. However, for reasons I can't figure out, it also produces a gap between the 3rd and 4th row, when all the xaml definitions are the same.

Any help that can be provided is greatly appreciated, and I apologize for the crude code - tidying up is high on the agenda.

Note 1; this grid lives in another grid. The parent row definition is set to auto

Note 2; If I extend the page design beyond this grid in the designer, it is rendered fine at design time, but the gap appears when entering debug.

Note 3; I copied the code into another instance of VS2012, and it seems to work fine both in design and debug....

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="75"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,1,1">A</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">B</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">C</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">D</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="4" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">E</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="5" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">F</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="6" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">G</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="7" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">H</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="8" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">I</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="9" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,1,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">J</Label>
                <Label Grid.Column="10" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,2,2,1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">K</Label>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" Padding="1" MinWidth="150"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="1">
                    <!--Combobox items-->
</Combobox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" Padding="1" MinWidth="150"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="2">
                    <!-- Combobox items -->
</ComboBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,1,1,1" Padding="1" MinWidth="150" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="Visible">
                    <!-- Combobox items -->
</ComboBox>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,1,1,2" Padding="1" MinWidth="150"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,2" Padding="1"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="4">
                    <!-- Combobox items -->
</ComboBox>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: I ran your code and don't see the gap. Can you post a picture of what the problem is?

Comment: Try setting `UseLayoutRounding="False"` on the grid . If it doesn't work, set `SnapToDevicePixels="False"`. If it still doesn't work, set both to true. Tell us what you get.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I played around with adding a couple more columns and for some reason the gap moved to between the 2nd and 3rd row of inputs.... @XAMeLi, setting both of these properties to true then removed the gap. Thank you very much!